# android sql cursor error

Tags: android, sql, cursor

Im playing with sql in android and found this issue:

Im reading data from my database:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SINGLE_APPS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_SINGLE_PACKAGE + "=?"
            , new String[]{packageName});

    SingleAppModel singleAppModel = new SingleAppModel();
```

and when I try to get cursor.getInt(3) over here:

```
    try {
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                singleAppModel.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                singleAppModel.setAppName(cursor.getString(1));
                singleAppModel.setPackageName(cursor.getString(2));
                singleAppModel.setState(cursor.getInt(3) == 1);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
```

It returns error:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`
```

Weird is that if I delete line where Im calling cursor.getInt(3), it works.
Colum with that value exists and Im sure its of type INTEGER.

Also the value of cursor.getColumnCount() is 4 and value of cursor.getCount() is 1 ... so there are definetly some data...

Any advice?

Thankyou.

Comment: I think your cursor is not what you are expecting. try putting debug point on the if condition and check what data is coming

Comment: What do you mean by debug point? Im kind of beginner programer so if you could be more accurate I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using * I suggest you to use,

```
 cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COL0, COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM " + TABLE_SINGLE_APPS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_SINGLE_PACKAGE + "=?"
            , new String[]{packageName});
```

Use the appropriate values for `COL0, COL1, COL2, COL3` according to your table.
That way you make sure that the order of the columns fetched in the query.

But according to this,

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`
```

I need more information to confirm, can you add your table schema, according to the issue there is no 3rd column in the database raw.

**Edit:**

This can be a small programmer mistake,

Look out for the onCreate and onUpgrade methods in SQLiteOpenHelper implementation

Comment: String CREATE_SINGLE_APPS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SINGLE_APPS + "("
                + COLUMN_SINGLE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_SINGLE_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_SINGLE_PACKAGE + " TEXT," + COLUMN_SINGLE_STATE + " INTEGER" + ")";

Comment: There is a huge possibility that your android application is using earlier database from your previous version, There is a specific way of handling this, you can uninstall the application and install it again, that way it will recreate the database fresh.

Comment: No I have tried this many times.. I have even deleted database manualy and recreated it..

Comment: Did you try taking this cursor.getInt(3) == 1 our of the method argument and place it separately, int x = cursor.getInt(3); and boolean t = x==1; singleAppModel.setState(t); This will give more insight to the issue.

Comment: int value = cursor.getInt(3);
                        singleAppModel.setState(value == 1);  tried it like this but still the same error :/